# How to change the element in a <i> tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to do something along the lines of:

```
var myTrack = document.getElementById('trackname');
...
case 1:
    myTrack.textContent = "Home 1";
    ...
```

but for an element in a i tag instead of a p tag:

```
<a href="#" class="secondary-content">
    <i id="arrow" class="material-icons"> arrow_forward </i>
</a>
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: a. Are you trying to change the icon? b. What are the conditions for change to occur? Please edit your question.

Comment: Have you tried ```var myArrow = document.getElementById('arrow')``` then ```myArrow.textContent = 'new content' ```?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? At the moment it is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The element id in `getElementById()` and the one in the html attribute must be the same. Then if you want to change the material icon dynamically I suggest you to place both the icons in place and manage them with css `display` property.